# SQL query selection help need

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table which has column called `payment_txn_status`

I have to write a query which shows distinct status code with their respective count.

My current query which is as below gives me only distinct status code but how to get count for each individual status code

```
select distinct  payment_txn_status FROM  tpayment_txn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and a [COUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx):

```
SELECT payment_txn_status, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM tpayment_txn
GROUP BY payment_txn_status
```